# Error when trying to execute mvn verify - Failed to execute goal com.lazerycode.jmeter:jmeter-analysis-maven-plugin:1.0.6:analyze

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-maven-plugin, jmeter-analysis-maven-plugin

I am trying to execute integration tests using jmeter-maven-plugin, via `mvn clean verify` but getting an error even though all tests pass successfully -

`Failed to execute goal com.lazerycode.jmeter:jmeter-analysis-maven-plugin:1.0.6:analyze (default) on project my-integrationtests: Error analysing: /Users/...../integration-tests/target/8165f138-3899-407e-ad2f-51402e4693e7/jmeter/bin/templates.dtd (No such file or directory)`

Versions:

`Apache Maven 3.6.3  Java version: 17.0.6 Default locale: en_IN, platform encoding: UTF-8 OS name: "mac os x", version: "13.5.2", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"`

POM:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
    <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.7.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
           <id>configuration</id>
           <goals>
              <goal>configure</goal>
           </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
           <id>jmeter-tests</id>
           <goals>
            <goal>jmeter</goal>
           </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
           <id>jmeter-check-results</id>
           <goals>
              <goal>results</goal>
           </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <generateReports>true</generateReports>
        <appendResultsTimestamp>true</appendResultsTimestamp>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
    <artifactId>jmeter-analysis-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.6</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
           <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
           <goals>
              <goal>analyze</goal>
           </goals>
           <configuration>  
                       <source>${project.build.directory}/**/*.xml</source>
                     <targetDirectory>${project.build.directory}/jmeter/results</targetDirectory>
               <sourceDirFailed>true</sourceDirFailed>  
                       <processAllFilesFound>true</processAllFilesFound>
           </configuration>
            </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

In the generated target folder I can see that templates.dtd is inside templates folder (templates/templates.dtd) and not directly in bin (bin/templates.dtd)

Logs:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.lazerycode.jmeter:jmeter-analysis-maven-plugin:1.0.6:analyze (default) on project my-integrationtests: Error analysing: /Users/...../integration-tests/target/55550f20-5509-45a8-b069-4daaf645953a/jmeter/bin/templates.dtd (No such file or directory) -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal com.lazerycode.jmeter:jmeter-analysis-maven-plugin:1.0.6:analyze (default) on project my-integrationtests: Error analysing
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Error analysing
    at com.lazerycode.jmeter.analyzer.AnalyzeMojo.execute (AnalyzeMojo.java:233)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/...../integration-tests/target/55550f20-5509-45a8-b069-4daaf645953a/jmeter/bin/templates.dtd (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0 (Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open (FileInputStream.java:216)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init> (FileInputStream.java:157)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init> (FileInputStream.java:111)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect (FileURLConnection.java:86)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream (FileURLConnection.java:189)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity (XMLEntityManager.java:653)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.startEntity (XMLEntityManager.java:1397)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.startDTDEntity (XMLEntityManager.java:1363)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDTDScannerImpl.setInputSource (XMLDTDScannerImpl.java:257)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.dispatch (XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1152)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.next (XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1040)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next (XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:943)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next (XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:605)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument (XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:542)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse (XML11Configuration.java:889)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse (XML11Configuration.java:825)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse (XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse (AbstractSAXParser.java:1224)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse (SAXParserImpl.java:637)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse (SAXParserImpl.java:326)
    at com.lazerycode.jmeter.analyzer.parser.JMeterResultParser.aggregate (JMeterResultParser.java:58)
    at com.lazerycode.jmeter.analyzer.ResultAnalyzer.analyze (ResultAnalyzer.java:42)
    at com.lazerycode.jmeter.analyzer.AnalyzeMojo.analyze (AnalyzeMojo.java:318)
    at com.lazerycode.jmeter.analyzer.AnalyzeMojo.execute (AnalyzeMojo.java:217)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
```